# In elisp, how to evaluate a string of "var=value\n..." into lisp variables of the same name?

Tags: emacs, elisp

An mplayer tool (`midentify`) outputs "shell-ready" lines intended to be evaluated by a bash/sh/whatever interpreter.

How can I assign these var-names to their corresponding values as elisp var-names in emacs?
The data is in a string (via `shell-command-to-string`)

Here is the data

```
ID_AUDIO_ID=0
ID_FILENAME=/home/axiom/abc.wav
ID_DEMUXER=audio
ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=1
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=512000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=0
ID_AUDIO_NCH=1
ID_LENGTH=3207.00
ID_SEEKABLE=1
ID_CHAPTERS=0
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=512000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=32000
ID_AUDIO_NCH=1
ID_AUDIO_CODEC=pcm
ID_EXIT=EOF
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a routine that takes a string containing `midentify` output, and returns an association list of the key-value pairs (which is safer than setting Emacs variables willy-nilly).  It also has the advantage that it parses numeric values into actual numbers:

```
(require 'cl)  ; for "loop"
(defun midentify-output-to-alist (str)
  (setq str (replace-regexp-in-string "\n+" "\n" str))
  (setq str (replace-regexp-in-string "\n+\\'" "" str))
  (loop for index = 0 then (match-end 0)
        while (string-match "^\\(?:\\([A-Z_]+\\)=\\(?:\\([0-9]+\\(?:\\.[0-9]+\\)?\\)\\|\\(.*\\)\\)\\|\\(.*\\)\\)\n?" str index)
        if (match-string 4 str)
        do (error "Invalid line: %s" (match-string 4 str))
        collect (cons (match-string 1 str)
                      (if (match-string 2 str)
                          (string-to-number (match-string 2 str))
                        (match-string 3 str)))))
```

You'd use this function like so:

```
(setq alist (midentify-output-to-alist my-output))
(if (assoc "ID_LENGTH" alist)
    (setq id-length (cdr (assoc "ID_LENGTH" alist)))
  (error "Didn't find an ID_LENGTH!"))
```

EDIT: Modified function to handle blank lines and trailing newlines correctly.

The regexp is indeed a beast; Emacs regexps are not known for their easiness on the eyes.  To break it down a bit:

- The outermost pattern is `^(?:valid-line)|(.*)`.  It tries to match a valid line, or else matches the entire line (the `.*`) in match-group 4.  If `(match-group 4 str)` is not `nil`, that indicates that an invalid line was encountered, and an error is raised.
- `valid-line` is `(word)=(?:(number)|(.*))`.  If this matches, then the name part of the name-value pair is in match-string 1, and if the rest of the line matches a number, then the number is in match-string 2, otherwise the entire rest of the line is in match-string 3.

Comment: I like your *willy-nilly* comment, because I just like the phrase, and it makes good sense. I had been wondering about that numeric issue (I figured I could just use *number-to-string*), so what you've done is great... but *holy-moly*! it will take me a week to figure out the regex (I've become used to extended regex with somwhat fewer backslashes :) ... I'll get used to it, I'm sure.... *but* :( I get an error: *(error "Invalid line: ")
  signal(error ("Invalid line: "))
  error("Invalid line: %s" "")
  (if (match-string 4 str) (error "Invalid line: %s" (match-string 4 str)) (cons (ma*

Comment: *@Sean:* Thanks for adding the newline fix... On a side note:  I wangled my way around the regex issue (for now, at least, until I get more used to elisp in general). I've made a wrapper which hopefully doesn't have some horrible side effects whichI'm not yet aware of.. I've called it [ree: Regex; Easy on the Eyes](http://paste.ubuntu.com/751190/) :) .. It uses C-), C-), C-| to insert Unicode look-alikes, and vice-versa. The script just switches the values depending on the existance of any of the 3 Unicode chars... eg: `(ree "^❨?:❨[A-Z_]+❩=❨?:❨[0-9]+❨?:\\.[0-9]+❩?❩❙❨.*❩❩❙❨.*❩❩\n?")`

Comment: Minor note, you don't need to `require` cl, `eval-when-compile` will suffice.  `loop` is a macro.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a better way but this should do it:

```
(require 'cl)

(let ((s "ID_AUDIO_ID=0
ID_FILENAME=/home/axiom/abc.wav
ID_DEMUXER=audio
ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=1
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=512000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=0
ID_AUDIO_NCH=1
ID_LENGTH=3207.00
ID_SEEKABLE=1
ID_CHAPTERS=0
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=512000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=32000
ID_AUDIO_NCH=1
ID_AUDIO_CODEC=pcm
ID_EXIT=EOF"))
  (loop for p in (split-string s "\n")
    do
    (let* ((elements (split-string p "="))
          (key (elt elements 0))
          (value (elt elements 1)))
      (set (intern key) value))))
```

Comment: Looking good. It does the trick as per the sample data, but it will have problems with a filename which contains spaces, eg.`ID_FILENAME=/home/axiom/a\\ b\\ \\ c.wav` (which is what midentify outputs).. or for some other situation which usese a quoted string (with spaces) ... Is there some way to tweak `split-string` to cater for this?

Comment: I've just changed the first call to split-string to split on newlines only.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function you can run on the output buffer:

```
(defun set-variables-from-shell-assignments ()
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (< (point) (point-max))
    (and (looking-at "\\([A-Z_]+\\)=\\(.*\\)$")
       (set (intern (match-string 1)) (match-string 2)))
    (forward-line 1)))
```

Comment: That should be [A-Z_]+ in this case.

Comment: Thanks *kevin*. This buffer (vs string) method will surely come in handy (soon)...

Comment: Thank you for ``loking-at`` thing. I really lacked this one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think regexp is what really need. You need to split your string by `\n` and `=`, so you just say exactly the same to interpreter.

I think you can also use `intern` to get symbol from string(and set variables). I use it for the first time, so comment here if i am wrong. Anyways, if list is what you want, just remove top-level mapcar.

```
(defun set=(str)
  (mapcar (lambda(arg)
            (set
              (intern (car arg))
              (cadr arg)))
    (mapcar (lambda(arg)
              (split-string arg "=" t))
      (split-string
        str
        "\n" t))))

(set=
"ID_AUDIO_ID=0
ID_FILENAME=/home/axiom/abc.wav
ID_DEMUXER=audio
ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=1
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=512000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=0
ID_AUDIO_NCH=1
ID_LENGTH=3207.00
ID_SEEKABLE=1
ID_CHAPTERS=0
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=512000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=32000
ID_AUDIO_NCH=1
ID_AUDIO_CODEC=pcm
ID_EXIT=EOF")
```

Comment: Thanks.. It isn't quite what I was after (but it's heading there), It is, however, certainly good for me to see this example of how you have split up the input.. I'm such a beginner at elisp, something like this is good to refer to.